# How do I read C arguments in Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

I'm currently building a (very simple) OS, using NASM. I'm trying to write an assembly function that will read a byte from an address given as a function parameter, then return the data, like so:

```c
// kernel.c
extern int readbyte();

int main(void) {
  int x = readbyte(0xdeadbeef); //returns data stored at 0xdeadbeef
  return 0;
}
```

```s
; kernel_entry.asm
[bits 32]
[extern main]
[extern readbyte]

call main

readbyte:
  ; somehow read function parameter here and store it to ecx
  mov eax, [ecx] ; read byte from given address
  ret ; return the data to the C function
```

Returning data via the `eax` register is working fine, but I can't figure out where the parameter data given by the C program (`0xdeadbeef`) is or how I can access it. When I try to pop from the stack, the whole program just crashes. I've tried reading from various registers, but those don't ever match up with the parameter given in the C script.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

Following Michael Petch's suggestion, I wrote an assembly function that returns the first parameter:

```s
readbyte:
  mov ecx, [esp + 4]
  mov eax, ecx
  ret
```

The issue is that when I test it in Qemu, the display rapidly flashes between the boot sequence screen and displaying the correct data. Does anybody know why it's crashing, yet also showing the proper data?

**Edit 2:**

So I discovered that the above code will run without entering a reboot loop if I pass a hexadecimal value less than 4 digits long. So `0xABC` will work properly, but `0xABCD` will crash the system.

Comment: In 32-bit code they are on the stack. Do not `pop` the stack to gain access as the return address is pushed on the stack for the function. When your function is called the return address will be at [esp+0] and the first parameter is as [esp+4], second parameter at [ESP+8] etc. You can read those memory addresses directly with something like `mov ecx, [esp+4]`. ECX should contain 0xdeadbeef

Comment: Note that `mov eax,[ecx]` is a dword-sized move from memory operation, whereas the function is called `readbyte`.  Suggest something like `movzx eax,[ecx]` (maybe even with `byte ptr [ecx]`)?

Comment: Why not just write a C function that does what you want, then compile it with `-S` and see what code is produced?

Comment: @ErikEidt I should add that I'm working in 32 bit code, not 64 bit. I'm not sure if that interferes with what you suggested, but I thought that might be helpful information.

Comment: Similar to what Tom suggested, you can compile `main`, and then look at the assembly to see where `main` puts `0xdeadbeef`. But in general, you should get a copy of the [application binary interface (ABI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). Good documentation is the key to success.

Comment: As a general tip, for successful OS development, you need to be up to speed with debugging tools, so that you don't ever have to get stuck at "it crashes and I have no idea why".  Single-step the code, identify the instruction which faults, think about why it does, then think about how it got to that point.  Bochs has a better debugger than qemu for such purposes.

Comment: Note that in this setting, "reboot loop" is the typical consequence of what would be a segfault in a normal program.  Invalid memory accesses cause a GPF or page fault.  At this stage in development, you probably haven't installed handlers for those exceptions, so the attempt to handle the exception causes another fault (double fault).  You don't have a handler for the double fault exception either, which is a triple fault.  This is unrecoverable and the machine can't do anything except reboot.

Comment: By the way, in C, `extern int readbyte();` is wrong.  The function takes an argument and so you need to declare it with a prototype giving the correct type of that argument.  Otherwise, you will get default argument promotions, which will appear to work until they don't.  The compiler will also not warn you if you pass the wrong number or type of arguments.  Make it `extern int readbyte(unsigned long);` or something of the kind.

Comment: A couple questions for the current version of your code: (1) `mov ecx, [esp+4]` gets you the address (e.g. `0xdeadbeef`) in ecx.  `mov eax, ecx` just copies that *address* into eax.  If you want to actually read from that address, you still need `mov eax, [ecx]`, or better `movzx` as Erik Eidt says.  (2) If you actually run that code, then it's probably going to crash anyway, unless you have set up your page tables to map some valid memory at address `0xdeadb000`.

Comment: (3) After `main` calls `readbyte`, it returns. You didn't write any more code to follow `call main`, so you fall through into the code that happens to come next, which happens to be `readbyte` again.  This now reads bogus data from unintended parts of the stack, and `ret`s to another random address off the stack.  That's going to crash for sure.

Comment: consider adding `cli` to disable interrupts and `hlt` halt instruction at end of execution and qemu will remain stable until you reset the simulation.

Comment: @NateEldredge That particular bit of code is just meant to echo the return the first argument, as a test to ensure that I can properly read it.

Comment: Falling through into `readbyte` again will execute `ret` instruction and jump to an unpredictable location.  That could easily crash and lead to another reboot.  If you just want to make a test program, you need an infinite loop at the end, preferably with a `hlt` inside it.  (Or `cli`/`hlt`, if you don't care about being able to reboot with ctrl+alt+del.)

Comment: @PeterCordes At the end of the program, I have a `jmp $` as an infinite loop.

Comment: That's not what your [mcve] shows.  It shows fall-through into `readbyte` after `main` returns.  If there's a `jmp $` after that, it won't be reached because the `ret` at the bottom of `readbyte` will pop the stack into IP, doing another jump.  Use a debugger to single-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern operating systems, that depends on the ABI (the set of rules that specify how the interface with a separately compiled module is established)  This assumes that some CPU registers are reserved for passing parameters (e.g. four of them) while the rest are pushed on the stack.  Let's assume that the ABI establishes that the first four registers are used to pass function arguments, and that you are called with e.g. 6 arguments, the way a function call is made is to first push the last two arguments to the stack (in reverse order to how they are written in the code, so first the last argument, then the fifth, and then the four registers are filled with the rest of arguments, then a call is made to the routine address, which means that the return address is also pushed on the stack.  Inside your routine, there's normally a function preamble code that consists in storing in a register the value of the stack pointer, by first pushing the value of this register to the stack in a form like the following:

```
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp
```

This will allow you to mangle with the stack pointer (pushing local storage or doing calculations) without having to consider the SP position to access parameters or the like, when accessing the function parameters.

Also, local storage is reserved, by subtracting (at this point) a proper value from the stack pointer.  This leads to the following stack:

```
       |  more stack... |
       +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
       |  sixth param   |
       +----------------+
       |  fifth param   |
       +----------------+ (previous parameters are in cpu registers)
       |  return address|
       +----------------+
       |  old value BP  | <--- BP points here now.
       +----------------+
       |  local vars    |
       .                .
       |                | <--- SP points here at function entry, after preamble
       +----------------+
       | local stack    |
```

So, you should use (in this case, for this function):

| address | to access... |
| --- | --- |
| `[EBP + 12]` | sixth parameter |
| `[EBP + 8]` | fifth parameter |
| `[EBP + 4]` | return address |
| `[EBP + 0]` | old linkage BP |
| `[EBP - 4]` | first local var |

But, as I say, you should conform to the ABI your compiler is using.  This should be found with your compiler documentation (or at least, a reference to the document describing it)

Consider also that the offsets depend on the variable size **and it’s alignment**. This is important.

At the end, by the way, there’s also some epilogue code, to undo the changes of the prologue. If you have been conservative with the stack, it should point to the same value as the EBP register, so **NO** `mov sp, ebp` will be needed, but

```
pop ebp
```

Will, to restore the old link register. This leaves the return address on top of the stack, and we can return. The calling procedure is responsible of adjusting the stack from this point on (popping the pushed stack registers used for the call)

Comment: `bp` is a 16-bit register.  Your stack layout is showing 8-byte gaps between stack slots, which would only apply for 64-bit code where the first 6 args are passed in registers.  The question is asking about 32-bit code.  (4-byte stack slots, with sizeof(int) = sizeof(void*) = 4, and the standard calling convention for GCC passes all args on the stack like you're talking about.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, I'm not talking about a specific architecture, but all of them do the same thing (so a multiple target compiler can do it in a generic way)  I've used the name `BP` in a generic way, but if you don't like the name I can change it for `A14` or the name you prefer.  Do you prefer `RBP` or `EBP`? Or `A14` or `base_pointer`, or `stack_frame_pointer`?

Comment: It's an x86 question, but feel free to make your answer non-specific instead of mismatched to itself and the question.   But in that case, you should have closed it as a duplicate of any number of question about base-pointer for stack access.  Anyway, `EBP` with 4-byte stack slots is obviously the right choice for matching the question, although generic names like `base_pointer` and `stack_pointer` would work.

Comment: Standard 32-bit x86 calling conventions pass no args in registers, so yeah, readers will have to adjust as necessary.

Comment: Sometimes I refuse to answer at all, because some people doesn't understand that to err is a human caracteristic.  Throwing down a complete answer by a small detail like the exact architecture is a bit cumbersome to animate people to do helping.  But thanks for the advice, correcting mistakes is also human.  Probably I've done more.... continue searching :)

Comment: Getting the details wrong can be very confusing for a beginner; they try your answer and find out it doesn't work, and assume the general concept you're trying to explain doesn't actually work or apply. I didn't downvote your answer, I just commented to point such problems. But anyway, if you just wanted to write a generic answer, why not post it on a generic question like [What is exactly the base pointer and stack pointer? To what do they point?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1395591) if none of those say exactly what you wanted to say, and close this as a duplicate of that or another arg-passing Q?

Comment: At least now the ESP/EBP usage matches the question and the 4-byte stack slots, but no standard 32-bit calling convention uses 4 arg-passing registers.  You're probably thinking of Windows x64 (which passes the first 4 args in RCX, RDX, R8, R9, and requires 32 bytes of shadow space), unlike Windows 32-bit fastcall which passes 2 args in ECX, EDX (where the OP's `mov eax, [ecx]` would be correct).  So yeah, read the ABI and/or look at compiler output for how it passes args.

Comment: My answer is general enough to contemplate both architectures, despite the sample code is 32bit specific.